# Proof of integrated volatility

Tags: probability, self-study, variance, proof, integral

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of iid standard normal random variables, $\sigma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}_+$ a continuous function. Define $r_{n,i}\equiv\frac{\sigma(i/n)X_i}{\sqrt{n}}$. Show that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nr_{n,i}^2\overset{p}{\to}\int_0^1\sigma^2(s)ds
$$

I managed to show that:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\sigma^2(i/n)X_i^2-\frac{1}{n}\sum\sigma^2(i/n)\overset{p}{\to}0
$$

But I don't know how to properly transform that second sum in an integral and still have the convergence.
Can anyone point me in a good direction or give me some tips? I don't want a complete solution.

Comment: Does this probably qualify as [`self-study`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)? If so, please add the tag.

Comment: So I hope this points you in 'a good direction'.  Is it clear to you that if the $r_{n,i}$ were defined as $r_{n,i}\equiv\frac{\sigma(i/n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ then the equality would make sense as an actual equality ?

Comment: @aginensky yes it does.

Comment: @aginensky I updated the question with something I just proved, but now I don't know how to deal with the convergence to the integral

Comment: The RHS is essentially the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.  You are done- once you interpret the RHS correctly.

Comment: @aginensky yeah, I noticed that, but I don't know how to "put it" in the RHS. I've tried using triangular inequality with the integral, and then add and subtract that sum, but it is not working =/

Comment: R-S integration proceed by dividing the total interval [0,1] into n subintervals.  So make them all of length 1/n . So interval i is $ [ \frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n} \]$ .  Choose the right hand end point i.e. the point i/n to evaluate the function.  I think that does it.